# Why SQLite method "sqlite3_step" doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I have an iOS SQLite project. I've created a class `DBHelper` initialising access to database as outlined in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@imbilalhassan/saving-data-in-sqlite-db-in-ios-using-swift-4-76b743d3ce0e) and wrote in `DBHelper` such functions as `createTable()` and `insert()` which work correctly and another one `read()` which should return an array with data. The beginning of this func looks like this:

```
func read() -> [DataModel]{
    let queryStatementString: String = "SELECT * FROM objects;"
    var queryStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
    var psns: [DataModel] = []
    
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStatementString, -1, &queryStatement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
        print("error preparing select: \(errmsg)")
    }
    print("\(sqlite3_step(queryStatement)) and \(SQLITE_ROW)")
    while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {
    //and here I try to declare variables like let name = String(describing: 
    // String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(queryStatement, 1)))
    // and then create a DataModel with these variables
```

The point is that the last string `while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW` is unreachable, and all code after this line don't compile.

The `print` in previous line throws in the console "101 and 100", and I guess this is the reason why `while` loop doesn't work properly.
Where should I find the reason of this bug?

Comment: Looks like you have no objects.  101 = SQLITE_DONE.

Comment: By the way, there are both stylistic and substantive issues with this tutorial’s `DBHelper`. See https://github.com/robertmryan/SQLiteDemo where I tried to clean up some of the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `print` statement is printing `101`, i.e. `SQLITE_DONE`, for the result of `sqlite3_step`, simply meaning that there is no data in the table.

You should double check your `insert` calls. It would seem that you haven't called `insert` like you think you have, or that call failed for some reason.

Assuming you ran this on the simulator, you can actually `print` the path for your database and then navigate there in macOS and examine what's in it. You can use the built-in macOS command line program `sqlite3` or use a third party tool (e.g. [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com/) or [Base](https://menial.co.uk/base/)).

For example, having determined the path for my particular instance of this app on this simulator, I then went to the command line, went to that directory, opened `sqlite3`, and confirmed that the rows I inserted in my code appeared in the table:

[image]

Or, in TablePlus:

[image]

Obviously, I'm using `person`, like in that tutorial, but use whatever table name you used when creating your table and inserting the data. And, needless to say, your path for the `cd` command will be different, so print your path in the `openDatabase` function, and use that for your diagnostic purposes.

---

In your code sample, you use the following code pattern:

```
print("\(sqlite3_step(queryStatement)) and \(SQLITE_ROW)")
while sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW {
    ...
}
```

If your table had one record in it, the `sqlite3_step` in the `print` statement would would retrieve it and the `sqlite3_step` in the `while` statement would then skip to the next record, and, because you're now at the end of the table, you would exit the loop. Bottom line, you're skipping the first row in your results with that extra `sqlite3_step` call in the `print` statement.

Remove that `print` statement. Or if you want to print it, make sure you don't introduce extraneous `sqlite3_step` calls. For example, you could do:

```
var rc = sqlite3_step(statement)

while rc == SQLITE_ROW {
    print("row", rc)

    ...
    rc = sqlite3_step(statement)
}

print("done", rc)

if rc != SQLITE_DONE {
    // print the error
}
```